# DatagramSocket Packets IPAddress being changed by router?

Tags: java, android, sockets, network-programming, datagram

I have created a server that will be run on my desktop to send and receive messages from clients. The clients app will be run on android. As of now, both programs start up, and the client is able to send the initial connection to the server. My desktop is connected to the internet via a router, which i have port-forwarded from the router to receive the info.

The server is able to receive all messages sent by the client. However, the server is unable to respond. I did a quick check on the received packet (server side), and it says the ipaddress for the packet is the IP for my router. Does that mean i will be unable to send a response, since all of my packets will get their IP changed to the local address of the router (because of the port-forwarding)?

Ill post some code below, although im not sure it will help. Thanks very much for your comments.

Server:

```
public class QuoteServerThread extends Thread {

protected DatagramSocket socket = null;
DatagramPacket dgp = null;
protected boolean running = true;
ArrayList<ConnectedUser> users = new ArrayList<>();
String state;
int port;
int userId;

public QuoteServerThread(String name, String state) throws IOException {
    super(name);
    port = 4445;
    userId = 1;
    socket = new DatagramSocket(port);
    this.state = state;
    this.state = "listening";
    System.out.println("Server Socket is now listening on port: " + port);
}

public void run() {
    while (running) {
        try {
            byte[] buf = new byte[256];

            // receive request
            final DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
            socket.receive(packet);
            if(packet.getData() == null){
                System.out.println(packet.getData());
                return;
            }
            else{
                System.out.println(packet.getData());
            }
            dgp = packet;
            String message = new String(packet.getData(), 0, packet.getLength());

            if(state.equals("listening")) {
                if(message.contains("newUser")){
                    ConnectedUser newUser = new ConnectedUser(userId, socket);
                    users.add(newUser);
                    System.out.println("connected users: " + users.size());

                    String msg = "ID/" + userId;

                    InetAddress IPAddress = packet.getAddress();
                    int _port = packet.getPort();
                    System.out.println(IPAddress + "," + _port);
                    DatagramPacket out = new DatagramPacket(msg.getBytes(), msg.length(), IPAddress, _port);
                    socket.send(out);

                    userId++;
                }
                else if(message.contains("ID/")){
                    String receivedMessage[] = message.split("/");

                    System.out.println(receivedMessage[0] + ", " + receivedMessage[1] + ", " + receivedMessage[2]);
                }
                else{
                    System.out.println(message);
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            running = false;
        }
    }
    socket.close();
}
```

}

Client:

```
public class QuoteServerThread extends Thread {

protected DatagramSocket socket = null;
protected boolean running = true;
TextView chatWindow;
TextView notification;
EditText chatBox;
MainActivity ma;
ScrollView sv;

public QuoteServerThread(MainActivity ma, TextView chatWindow, EditText chatBox, ScrollView sv, TextView notification) throws IOException {
    this("QuoteServerThread");
    this.ma = ma;
    this.chatWindow = chatWindow;
    this.sv = sv;
    this.chatBox = chatBox;
    this.notification = notification;
}

public QuoteServerThread(String name) throws IOException {
    super(name);
    socket = new DatagramSocket();
}

public void run() {
    while (running) {
        try {
            byte[] buf = new byte[256];

            // receive request
            final DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
            socket.receive(packet);

            if(packet.getData() == null){
                System.out.println("data was null!");
                return;
            }

            String message = new String(packet.getData(), 0, packet.getLength());

            final String notif = message;
            notification.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    notification.setText("server " + "__msg: " + notif);
                }
            });


            if(ma.state.equals("connected")) {
                final String chatText = chatWindow.getText().toString() + "\n" + "Sender: " + message;
                chatWindow.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        chatWindow.setText(chatText);
                        sv.post(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                sv.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
                                chatBox.post(new Runnable() {
                                    public void run() {
                                        chatBox.requestFocus();
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
            else if(ma.state.equals("waitingconnection")){
                String msgSplit[];
                if(message.contains("ID/")){
                    msgSplit = message.split("/");

                    final String id = msgSplit[1];
                    ma.clientID = Integer.getInteger(id);


                    notification.post(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            notification.setText("connected to server " + "__msg: " + id);
                            ma.state = "connected";
                        }
                    });
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            running = false;
        }
    }
    socket.close();
}
```

}

the only issue here is the client not receiving a response. to state the problem again, I believe that the port forwarding on my router is changing the packets address to its local ipaddress (my phone is sending from mobile network). Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Comment: I may have found the error in my numerous tests. If i figure it out tomorrow i will update this post with the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue above was due to code that I had running in the background. When sending a message, I was using a class called MsgSender. MsgSender, however, was creating a new socket and sending the data. After the data was sent, it closed the socket, no longer listening for a response from the server.

To fix this, I shared the socket that is left open, and send all data through the single socket, so that it can listen for any information that is returned.

Be sure that when you send information, if you need to listen for a response, you MUST listen through the socket it was sent from. If you are not needing to listen for a response from the data you will be sending, you can close the socket.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are seeing effects of the network address translation (NAT) and port-forwarding. From the viewpoint of the android client it is communicating with your router. Then your router instead of processing messages itself offloads the processing to your server (port forwarding).

On your server you see the destination address. Since your android client is talking to your router, the destination IP address you see is that of your router.

If you want to reply, what you should to is take the source address of the datagram and send the reply back to that address. When you datagram will be passing the router with NAT it will change the source address to that of the router.